# How to send api response compressed in nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js

Chrome Lighthouse tells me that I could save like 90% of the transfered bytes by compressing my api route

How could I modify this code (api/something.js) to enable compression?

```js
export default {
    path: '/api/something',
    async handler(req, res) {
        let data = await obtainDataSomehow();
        res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
}
```

Static files and rendered routes are already compressed, I only have trouble with api routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1: Express & compression middleware

If you make the [server middleware extend Express](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware/#custom-api-endpoint), then you can use the [compression middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression) to handle compression of HTTP responses:

For example:

```js
    import express from 'express';
    import compression from 'compression';
    
    const app = express();
    // NB: compression threshold set to 0 for demonstration purposes only;
    //     this should be set to a higher value, such as the default 1 kb
    //     in live applications
    app.use(compression({ threshold: 0 }));
    
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      const data = { success: true };
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
    
    export default {
      path: '/api/something',
      handler: app
    }
```

This can be tested from the command-line like:

```
    curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -i http://localhost:3000/api/something
```

Which will show the response header `Content-Encoding: gzip`

## Option 2: delegate to gateway/reverse proxy

If you have your live deployment running behind a gateway or reverse proxy like NGINX, Apache, Cloudflare, etc, you can let that handle compression instead of needing to make your server middleware(s) do so.

In this scenario, you could also disable compression of the other resources by the Nuxt [renderer in nuxt.config.js](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-render/#compressor):

```js
    export default {
      render: {
        compressor: false
      }
    };
```